# Format text File based on log dates

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains server logs. So i need to format this txt file searching based on dates within the file and introduce new line characters at specific date points.

**Sample Content:**

25-Sep-2013 05:56:54 ERROR [com..webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-8 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Token expired.25-Sep-2013 06:48:21 ERROR [com.webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-9 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Token expired.25-Sep-2013 06:49:58 ERROR [com..webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-2 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Invalid customer context25-Sep-2013 06:49:58 ERROR

**I want it to formated as :**

25-Sep-2013 05:56:54 ERROR [com..webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-8 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Token expired.

25-Sep-2013 06:48:21 ERROR [com..webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-9 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Token expired.

25-Sep-2013 06:49:58 ERROR [com..webservice.security.AuthTokenSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal : 92] :: http-bio-8480-exec-2 :: Auth token validation failed with error : Invalid customer context

25-Sep-2013 06:49:58 ERROR

Comment: instead of formatting output log file you could write formatted server logs. configure logger properties properly.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Scanner] class.
Use [Scanner.findwithinhorizon()] method to find the occurrences of dates in the file and insert newline "\n" characters before each occurrences.

Check these references, these will help you get started.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_findwithinhorizon_string.htm